# can we create a vpc add AZ, IG, ACL, SG through ansible playbook?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I am trying to create a vpc add AZ to it with security groups and acl is it possible through ansible and how ?

Comment: I have successfully created EC2 instance through ansible playbook but how do i terminate the same instance through ansible playbook without access to AWS console?

Answer (score 0):

The new version of ansible supports this. But terraform would be a better approach for this if you have flexibility of choosing the tools. In terraform the existing infrastructure status is stored and is restored in case anything is not working. If you want to use only ansible then there are in build modules written in ansible for that. You will get all such info on the ansible docs.